# delete extra text and punctuation marks from the string keeping just smileys?

Tags: c#, regex, emoticons

I am running into some problems using the regular expression. Can you please help me out? The following in the problem I am trying to solve -

> **Input**:   :,... :D..:::))How are you today :P?..:(*
>
> **Output**  *:D :) :P :(*

Basically I want to remove the punctuations and text from the input string like-(.,:;  etc) and replace them with empty string. But I want to keep the smilies -:) ,:( OR :P .I have written the following code but it is not working.

> > Regex= "[A-Za-z]|:[D(P(]"

but it also remove the ":D and :P" smilie.

Comment: Are you keeping anything aside from smileys?

Comment: Are smileys the only thing you are keeping from the input string?

Comment: Emotions... the only kind of expression that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex string should work for you:

```
(((?<!:)[^:])|(:(?![PD\(\)])))[^:]*
```

It's made up of two parts:

1. ( `((?<!:)[^:])`  |  `(:(?![PD\(\)]))` )
2. `[^:]*`

The first part is an OR (`|`) statement that uses [Negative Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  It finds the first character in a block of text that doesn't contain a smiley by looking for either:

A character that is obviously not in a smiley:

1. Any character that is not preceded by a colon: `(?<!:)`
2. and is not a colon itself: `[^:]`

OR a colon that is not followed by a smiley character:

1. A colon `:`
2. That is not followed by a character that is the second half of a smiley: `(?![PD\(\)]))`

The second part (`[^:]*`) continues looking until we find the beginning of a potential smiley (a colon).

This Regex currently only finds the following smileys:

- :D
- :P
- :(
- :)

You can update the second half of the OR statement to find other smileys.

To sum it up, this Regex should find everything that is not part of a smiley.  You can simply declare it in a [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43122zyz.aspx) variable and then call [`.Replace(string input, string replacement)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx), passing in your input string and the string you want to replace the non-smiley characters with (`String.Empty` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Not so perfect solution:

```
string text = ":,... :D..:::))How are you today :P?..:(*";
text = text.Replace(":)", "@@@)");
text = text.Replace(":D", "@@@D");
text = text.Replace(":P", "@@@P");

// clean up your punctuation marks here
//

text = text.Replace("@@@)", ":)");
text = text.Replace("@@@D", ":D");
text = text.Replace("@@@P", ":P");
```